# How can I set the number of keepers allowed in Yahoo! Fantasy Baseball?

Tags: yahoo-fantasy-sports

I have renewed my long-running fantasy baseball league. The league is set as a "keeper" league, but I can't find the screen where I can specify how many roster spots can be kept.

How can I set the number of keepers allowed in Yahoo! Fantasy Baseball?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Yahoo! support (emphasis mine):

> Hello Jeromy,
>
> Thank you for contacting Yahoo Fantasy Sports. I appreciate your
> inquiry regarding keepers. I'll be happy to clarify the situation.
>
> **There is no ability to specify how many keepers can be kept. It will be up to you as commissioner to ensure the appropriate number of
> keepers are kept for each team using the approve keeper players
> tool.**
>
> When a league declares a keeper declaration deadline, once
> that deadline passes the commissioner can use the Confirm Keeper
> Players tool to review the keepers submitted by each team, change them
> if needed to comply with league rules, and eventually confirm that the
> keeper declaration is complete, publishing the results.
>
> Please note: The commissioner is required to complete this process prior to a
> scheduled live draft, or the draft will fail to run. If the
> commissioner changes any of the team's keepers, this change will be
> noted in a transaction to improve league communication and discourage
> unethical changes by the commissioner.
>
> Please note: If your Keeper
> Declaration Deadline is in the future, or if you have not finalized
> your team list, you will not be able to confirm keepers. To approve
> keepers:
>
> 1. Commissioners should log in to your Fantasy league.
> 2. In the "Fantasy" tab drop-down menu, select the league you want to work on.
> 3. Select the Commish Tools tab.
> 4. In the "Keeper Management" section, select Approve Keeper Players.
> 5. Review and edit the keepers selected by each team. To edit a team's keepers, click the Edit Keepers button beneath the team's roster.
> 6. When you are done reviewing and making any changes, select Approve All Keepers and proceed to edit your league's draft. Note: The Confirm
>    Keeper Players tool is available until approximately one hour prior to
>    the start of your draft. Additional information on this, and other
>    Yahoo products, can be found on the Yahoo help page.
>
> If you have any further concerns regarding this issue Jeromy, please
> let me know and I will be happy to assist you.